# How to access Kusto by Managed Identity from developer's local desktop?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, azure-managed-identity

We're change Kusto client authentication from application key to  Managed Identity. Our service can access Kusto by system management identity from VMSS. The API we are using is WithAadSystemManagedIdentity().

But, local desktop cannot be authorized. I tried either system management identity or user management identity, none of them working.

Looks like the role assignment is missing for Microsoft users. I cannot find related document about adding user's role assignment.

By the way, the user principle has been added on data explorer cluster. I can access using application key from local

Answer (score 1):

There is no implementation for managed identity on the local machine, therefore the recommendation is to use Azure.Identity package and .WithAadTokenProvider and implement token retrieval yourself